# Is there a hindi to hindi dictionary?

Tags: dictionary

I want a Hindi - Hindi dictionary app for my ubuntu 14.04 lts. If there is one, please tell me about one. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can install an Hindi-Hindi dictionary with **Goldendict**

First install Goldendict:

```
sudo apt-get install goldendict
```

Then download the Hindi-Hindi dictionary file from [**Here**](http://www.mediafire.com/download/0xlymmov5ge/hindi-to-hindi-dictionary-thesaurus-1.20.utf16.dsl.dz)

Then follow [**This**](http://www.ihaveapc.com/2011/10/how-to-install-and-use-goldendict-dictionary-software-in-linux-mint-ubuntu/) article for install the dictionary file in Goldendict.

Comment: How do I use the Hindi-Hindi dictionary file?